# Static method changing state of Object

Tags: java, oop, static, static-methods

today i have stumbled on a code which i have seen in my project and was worried looking into it. I dont realize why they have made these as static methods as they change state of object within them.

below is the code

```
@Controller
CruiseController{

getCruiseSearchResults(){
//prepare cruise serach request, static method in CruiseHelper
CruiseSearchRequest cruiseReq = CruiseHelper.prepareRequest();
...futher impl      

}

/** my helper class which has utlity methods */
CruiseHelper{
    public static CruiseSearchRequest prepareRequest(){
        CruiseSearchRequest cruiseRequest = new CruiseSearchRequest();

    // all below methods are static
    setCruiseTypeandDestination(cruiseRequest)
    setStartAndEndDate(cruiseRequest)
    setShipAndDeparturePort(cruiseRequest)
    setDurationAndAccesiblity(cruiseRequest)
    setPromoType(cruiseRequest)
    setResultPreferences(cruiseRequest)

    return cruiseSearchCriteriaDTO
}

static void setCruiseTypeandDestination(CruiseSearchRequest cruiseRequest){

    /** changing the state of object in static method */
    cruiseRequest.setCruiseType("ABC");
    cruiseRequest.setCruiseType("Alaska");
}

//.... further static methods as above, all of them 
//change the state of cruiseRequest
}
```

So i know that, above methods **should not be static** as they all have properties of each request. But the code is working and has not failed on any load test performed.

my important question is : "can this above code be considered ??" and "can this fail, if yes. then in what scenario ?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, these methods change the state of an object, but it's an object that is given as a parameter to them, which is perfectly valid and makes sense.

`static` means that the method is bound to the object definition (the class) and not to any specific object instance. Thus static method **cannot** change the state of it's own object as it simply does not have an instance to work on (it does not have a `this`).

I suggest you read this about static and class variable : [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are used to imply that that method doesn't need an instance of the class to be called. For example consider the String class. It can still change the state of any object.

`replaceAll()` is not a static method as it needs an instance to work on. where as `valueOf()` isn't as it doesn't need a String instance.

I suggest you revisit the basics of Java.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont realize why they have made these as static methods as they change state of object within them.

Because they're methods of a class called `CruiseController`. They are modifying instances of a `CruiseSearchRequest`, a different class. You could not do `cruiseSearchRequest.setCruiseTypeandDestination();`, because the method `setCruiseTypeandDestination` isn't on the `CruiseSearchRequest` class. So, instead, it receives the  `CruiseSearchRequest` object as a parameter, and since it isn't tied to any instance of `CruiseController`, it is a static method of that class.

You could make the methods non-static *if* you moved them to the `CruiseSearchRequest` class. However, you don't need to. There is absolutely nothing technically wrong with modifying objects in a static method. It might or might not be a good design for your particular program, but it will not "fail".

Answer (score 0):

Methods in Spring shouldn't be static not because they won't work but becouse it is a bad decision in terms of your application architecture. Static methods are wrong decision in terms of unit testing - it is harder to mock static methods than objects. Also I think intensive usage of static methods breaks the concept of dependency injection and the code becomes more tightly-coupled. [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/java-static-methods-can-be-code-smell.html) is a nice article on this topic.